# Remove hashbang for incoming urls in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, single-page-application

Is it possible to remove the hashbang from angularjs URLs when redirecting users from another webpage?

I have a website in AngularJS and I've been able to remove the hashbang symbols from the address bar for all URLs within my page (when redirecting from one view to another). I used HTML5Mode according to the angularjs API:
https://docs.angularjs.org/#html5-mode

However if I try to link to my website from somewhere else without using the hashbang I get "Cannot GET /home". The URL I'm testing with is https://localhost:9001/home. This works within the page but not directly pasted to address bar.

I wonder if HTML5Mode only works within webpages but I can't find a clear explanation.

I configured the app this way:

```
.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {  
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });
```

### Update

I am using gulp as my testing server (I forgot to mention that). The only change required was to add the "fallback" parameter to enable rerouting.

```
gulp.task('start-server', function () {
  connect.server({
  port: port,
  root: appHome,
  http: false,
  fallback: 'app/index.html',
  livereload: true,
  middleware: function () {
    return [cors];
  }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't happen when you access from other website, it happens on page **refresh**. You need to change your routing in `.htaccess` for html5mode to work as intended

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix this with the routing. I was looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you'll either need to:

Create a rewrite rule to rewrite the links to your root index page
adjust your JS so that it generates the hashtag instead of the URL.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)     
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove hash tag for the pretty url. just follow these steps:

1.add base url in **index.html** inside head tag `<base href="/" />`.

2.enable the html 5 mode true in the Cofig file

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

3.Removing # from href links.

4.if you use Apache configure `.htaccess` file for [Refering](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/). 
html5mode require backend rewrite rule so you have to done this also .